# OAuth2/OpenID Connect - How to persist user identity across microservices?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, openid-connect, identityserver4

If you have a SPA (single page application) calling Service A with an access token, and in return, Service A calls an "internal" Service B, what is the standards driven approach for persisting the user identity to Service B?

For example, should you have Service A simply pass on the JWT token that it received to Service B?

If there is no real industry accepted standard for this use case, is it acceptable to pass JWT tokens around between internal services (as opposed to each internal service retrieving its own token to call other services)?

Comment: Yes it is. 
But, I think that, in the SPA case, the "best way" is to redirect to the Service B in your response to a request in you Service A. 
SPA -> Service A
SPA -> Service B

Obviously, I can understand that sometimes, you don't have other choices and do an internal call.

Comment: Assuming that Service B trusts the Authentication of Service A, I think that the id_token should be used to persist the user Identity. You can include multiple Audiences (aud) values as long as the Authorized party (azp) parameter is present. -> 2.2.  ID Token https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html